# UIAlertViewController of type action sheet with dynamic list of buttons

Tags: ios, ios8, uialertcontroller

As `UIAlertView` and `UIActionsheet` is deprecated from iOS 8.So it is advised not to use both of these two classes.With old action sheet method I could able to add tabs dynamically with the help of for loop.

```
UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc]init];
actionSheet.title = @"Departure City";
actionSheet.delegate = self;
actionSheet.tag = 1;

for (int j =0 ; j<arrayDepartureList.count; j++)
{
    NSString *titleString = arrayDepartureList[j];
    [actionSheet addButtonWithTitle:titleString];
}
```

and I can use button index in delegate method to perform appropriate action.This way I can create action sheet on the fly. So with `UIAlertController` class how this can be achieved,I am asking this because in `UIAlertController` class we have to add action handlers with their action block.

Comment: how did u do this?

Comment: please refer accepted answers below

Answer (score 8):

Since `UIActionSheet` is deprecated in iOS 8, you must use `UIAlertViewController` and add every action as this example:

```
UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"My Alert"
        message:@"This is an action sheet." 
        preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];
UIAlertAction *firstAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"one"
        style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
            NSLog(@"You pressed button one");
        }];
UIAlertAction *secondAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"two"
        style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
            NSLog(@"You pressed button two");
        }];

[alert addAction:firstAction];
[alert addAction:secondAction];

[self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
```

According to your example you can add `UIAlertAction` in the for loop and the action leads to some function that handles the selection.

**Another Solution i prefer:** 
Use [ActionSheetPicker](https://github.com/skywinder/ActionSheetPicker-3.0), to select your departure cities from a picker instead of a button for each city you can find it here:
https://github.com/skywinder/ActionSheetPicker-3.0

Comment: I can use this way but number of actions are dynamic so i can add action in uiactionsheet in for loop but how to link action handlers to those actions in same loop.

Comment: As i mentioned you can call the same function to the handler with the UIAlertAction as a parameter and handle it in the function according to the action title

Comment: Thanks for suggestion again...I did it.

Answer (score 4):

Just do the same like you did here.

```
for (int j =0 ; j<arrayDepartureList.count; j++)
{
    NSString *titleString = arrayDepartureList[j];
    UIAlertAction * action = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:titleString style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:nil];

    [alertController addAction:action];
}
```

if you need custom action for every action, you can define them in the handler section.

For further info, take a look here:
http://hayageek.com/uialertcontroller-example-ios/

Comment: Thanks for suggestion,but I have one doubt how can add action handler specific to particular action in same for loop or any other.How to map which action is for which action handler.

Answer (score 4):

It can be done by following way..

```
UIAlertController *departureActnSht = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Departure City"
                                                                          message:@"Select your choice"
                                                                   preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];

for (int j =0 ; j<arrayDepartureList.count; j++)
{
    NSString *titleString = arrayDepartureList[j];
    UIAlertAction *action = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:titleString style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action){

        self.txtDepartureCity.text = arrayDepartureList[j];
    }];

    [departureActnSht addAction:action];
}

UIAlertAction *cancelAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleDestructive handler:^(UIAlertAction *action){

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:departureActnSht completion:nil];
}];

[departureActnSht addAction:cancelAction];
[self presentViewController:departureActnSht animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 4):

**Swift 4**

`UIAlertController` with dynamic `UIAlertAction`

- Create an array of `String` for buttons title

```
let buttonTitles = ["First", "Second", "Third"]
```

- Closure

```
typealias completionWithValueAndIndex = (_ actionTitle :String, _ index: Int) ->()
```

- Define a method `showAlertsList`

```
func showAlertsList(title: String, message: String, buttonsTitle:[String], completion: completionWithValueAndIndex? = nil) {
        let alert = UIAlertController(  title: title,  message:message, preferredStyle: .alert)
        let handler = { (action: UIAlertAction) -> Void in
            let index = alert.actions.firstIndex { $0 == action}
            completion?(action.title ?? "", index ?? 0)
        }
        for i in 0..<buttonsTitle.count {
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: buttonsTitle[i], style: .default, handler: handler))
        }
        
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
 }
```

- Use the method

```
showAlertsList(title: "Test title", message: "Test message", buttonsTitle: buttonTitles) { actionTitle, index in
     print(actionTitle)
     print(index)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 let arrayList = ["Agra","Banglore","delhi","Mumbai"]
        let optionMenu = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "Choose City", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
        for i in arrayList{
            let cityName = UIAlertAction(title: i, style: .default, handler:
            {
                (alert: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in



           print(i)

        })
        optionMenu.addAction(cityName)

    }

    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler:
    {
        (alert: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
        print("Cancelled")
    })
    optionMenu.addAction(cancelAction)
    self.present(optionMenu, animated: true, completion: nil
```

Answer (score 0):

go plain, in case you DO need index (or PK, or similar...)
    import UIKit

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    showAlertWith(msg: "when to start:", btnTitles:
        [
            "Now",
            "15 secs",
            "30 secs",
            "1 min.",
        ])
}



class TaggedAlertAction: UIAlertAction{
    var tag = 0
}

final private func showAlertWith(msg: String, btnTitles: [String]){

    let alert = UIAlertController(
        title: title,
        message:msg,
        preferredStyle: .alert)

    let handler = { (act: TaggedAlertAction) in
        let ta = act as! TaggedAlertAction
        let tag = ta.tag

        print(tag)
    }

    for i in 0..<btnTitles.count {
        let a = TaggedAlertAction(title: btnTitles[i], style: .default, handler: handler
        a.tag = i+1 // or Whatever number You need...
        alert.addAction(a)
    }
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

}

Answer (score -1):

you can add action to UIAlertViewControler according to any dynamic list. use a simple for loop and create UIAction in each iteration. better to set tag values and perform actions according to your defines tag, Here is sample code. hope it helps 
https://github.com/Usman4Whizpool/UIAlertController